# Analyzing the wave data of the currently played music track

Tags: android, audio, buffer, wave

I can't seem to find the proper audio source for recording/analyzing/receiving the currently played music track (or just any playing media). I'm not talking about the Mic.

The spectrum live wallpaper does this on the Nexus One AFAIK.

How can I keep receiving wave buffers of the currently playing media?
(I would like to support everything from 1.5, but 2.1 specific solutions are also welcome)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official MusicVisualizer wallpaper uses a hidden API MediaPlayer.snoop(). But apparently it's not exposed in the SDK:

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/168c0dd235a12cc2/2824a7bb3359b4ad?show_docid=2824a7bb3359b4ad&pli=1